# How can I retrieve the P4 ROOT variable value in a Windows Batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, environment-variables, perforce

I want to retrieve the p4 CLIENT ROOT variable that appears in p4 info but not sure how. I am new to batch scripts myself. I've taken a look at http://answers.perforce.com/articles/KB_Article/Accessing-Perforce-Environment-Variables-From-a-Windows-Batch-File but I changed CLIENT to ROOT but it doesn't seem to work.

EDIT:
I've found a way to make the commands in that tutorial to work but that defeats the purpose of what I am trying to achieve because I have to manually set P4ROOT in the command line. Instead I am assuming I don't know the root folder so I want to find it from p4 info somehow.

Comment: Perforce is a client-server system, and the client root is different from the server root (typically, the client and server are not even on the same machine). P4ROOT is the server root, but your question seems to talk about retrieving the client root. Are you writing a trigger to be run by the server? Or are you building a client-side tool? Figuring out whether you want the client root or the server root is key to determining how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse the output of `p4 set P4CLIENT` to get the client name, then parse the output of `p4 client clientname` to get the root.  Ugly, but functional:

```
@for /f "tokens=2 delims== " %c in ('p4 set P4CLIENT') do @(for /f "tokens=2" %r in ('p4 client -o %c ^| findstr /c:"Root:" ^| findstr /v #') do echo %r)
```

If you're using this in a batch file, double each of the percent signs.

**EDIT** - Alternately, and much easier, now that I look at it:

```
for /f "tokens=3" %r in ('p4 info ^| findstr /c:"Client root:"') do echo %r
```

Again, double the percents if you're using this in a batch file.

Comment: When you can, it would be great if you can explain what each bit does in the for loop :)

Answer (score 2):

As Bryan noted, the client root and the server root are two different things, and it's good to be clear on which one it is you're trying to get (it sounds like you want to get the client root for the current client; this is set in the client spec and **not** in any environment variable on either the client or server side).  You can get them both from the output of "p4 info", though, and you can use the -F global option to p4 to isolate either field with minimal fuss:

Client root:

```
p4 -Ztag -F %clientRoot% info
```

Server root:

```
p4 -Ztag -F %serverRoot% info
```

See http://www.perforce.com/blog/130826/fun-formatting for more on the -F option.